# GWT custom widgets height

Tags: gwt, height

I need a custom widget height. I tried using this

```
Integer.toString(yourWidget.getElement().getOffsetHeight())
```

but,

- If I use it when I create it or add it to the container panel, it returns 0
- If I use it in the contrainer panel's `onLoad` method, it returns the widget height before the style is applied

So, when should I use it to get the widget height after the style is applied?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't known if you've solved your problem already, but an option to use JSNI would be making sure that the widget creation is finished.

A way of achieving that is with the Deferred command:

```
    DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command() {
        public void execute() {
            // Ask here for the height
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thx a lot! ir works perfect!, however DeferredCommand now is deprecated, so I used Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {...

Answer (score 0):

I think onAttach or onLoad would be a good catch..

```
@Override
protected void onLoad() {
   super.onLoad();
   //do sth
}
```

Comment: How about tools like Firebug - do they show the value you expect or does the height stay the same? (there are many ways the CSS can affect the height of an element - not always in the way you'd expect)

Comment: I remember I had the same problem a looong time ago.. And just can't remember how it was solved... basically the problem was that i was trying to change height while the widget was still not completely constructed... I-ll try to find the code...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same kind of problem that the one exposed here: [GWT - Retrieve size of a widget that is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692097/gwt-retrieve-size-of-a-widget-that-is-not-displayed)

They used a workaround using JSNI to do what they wanted, maybe a similiar trick will work for you as well.