# How to get the rendered size of a <div>

Tags: gwt, size

I have a `FlowPanel`, whose height is fixed (it is actually a percentage of its parent's height, which is fixed).
In this panel, I add several `div` elements. Using CSS, I set its height as 100% of its parent.
What I want to do is set its width to be equal to its height using javascript.

The issue I have is that I don't know when to run this bit of javascript. I tried adding it to the `onLoad()` method of my container, but the height is not known yet (`getOffsetHeight()` returns 0).

I had a look at similar questions (like [GWT - Retrieve size of a widget that is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692097/gwt-retrieve-size-of-a-widget-that-is-not-displayed)), but they were not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defer the call to `getOffsetHeight()` until the end of the event loop:

```
@Override
public void onLoad() {
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
      // Get and work with the element's offsetHeight.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I didn't know anything about the Scheduler, and it looks like something I will be using now and then. A big thanks for this :)

Comment: @Jason Terk I couldn't get this work correctly in GWTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108858/how-to-detect-if-a-view-is-fully-rendered