# How to detect if a View is fully rendered?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, gwtp

I have a couple of GWT widgets which are displayed in a view.

The view contains content like this:

```
FlowPanel mainPanel = new FlowPanel();
RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
Label label = new Label("test");
mainPanel.add(label);
FlowPanel otherPanel = new FlowPanel();
mainPanel.add(otherPanel);
```

The mainPanel gets its final height after the view has been fully rendered. I need to get the value of height from the mainPanel after the render process is completed.

Here is what I do so far:

```
    new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = $(mainPanel).height();
            // do something with the mainPanel height
        }
    }.schedule(300);
```

Noite: $(mainPanel) is the use of [GWTQuery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/).
I set a timer to hope that the view render process is completed when the timer fires. I suppose this is not a very clever solution.

**How can I detect if the view is fully rendered in order to get the final height of the mainPanel?**

**Edit:**

I also tried to use:

```
@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            // get mainPanel height is incorrect
        }
    });
}
```

but it seems that the rendering was not completed so the mainPanel did not have the correct height.

**Edit:**

It seems that the Scheduler works different on mobile and desktop when using SDM. I created a demo project (https://github.com/confile/GWT-2.7-Scheduler-Test) to show the problem.

I created another question for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128787/gwt-2-7-scheduler-works-different-on-mobile-and-desktop-in-sdm

Comment: May this will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/8012588/768894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gwt itself gives you a hook to do it. It is [onLoad()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onLoad()). You can override it.

Example. If you want to know when widgets of a FlowPanel are rendered, you can use

```
FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel(){
                      @Override
                      protected void onLoad()
                      {
                        //Do your stuff here
                      }};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Scheduler, not Timer. See [GWT: Timer and Scheduler Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368316/gwt-timer-and-scheduler-classes/12371520#12371520), which explains the distinction.

UPDATE:

Also, what is `$(mainPanel)`? You should do:

```
 int height = mainPanel.getOffsetHeight();
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried Scheduler but it seems that the rendering is not finished when scheduler deferred is executed.

Comment: That's impossible. Browsers only have one thread - they cannot execute code in parallel. Anyway, you have a different problem - I updated my answer.

Comment: @$(mainPanel) is the use of [GWTQuery][1]. Which Scheduler method would you use in my case?

Comment: If `mainPanel.getOffsetHeight()` returns zero in `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred`, there is some other problem in your code.

Comment: I use GWTP and when I use the onReveal() method (see my edit) then the mainPanel is not zero but is is also not the final size.

Comment: Okay I think there is a problem in GWT SDM the Scheduler works different on desktop and mobile here is a demo project for that: https://github.com/confile/GWT-2.7-Scheduler-Test

Answer (score -1):

This was posted in [How to detect if a page has fully rendered using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630904/how-to-detect-if-a-page-has-fully-rendered-using-jquery)

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //everything is loaded
});
```

Comment: This does not work because my window is loaded and I only change dom elements. I am using GWTP. So the load event will not fire again.

Comment: Why would you post jQuery answer in  GWTP question?